# Flatten a nested array into rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with a nested array field (events).

```
-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- events: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to flatten the data and get a dataframe with a schema similar to this:

```
-- id: long (nullable = true)
-- key: string (nullable = true)
-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

example input:

```
+-----+-------------------------------------------------------+
|id   |             events                                    |
+-----+-------------------------------------------------------+
|  1  | [[john , 1547758879, 1], [bob, 1547759154, 1]]        |
|  2  | [[samantha , 1547758879, 1], [eric, 1547759154, 1]]   |
+-----+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

example putput:

```
+-----+---------+----------+-----+
|id   |key      |timestamp |value|
+-----+---------+----------+-----+
|  1  |john     |1547758879|    1|
|  1  |bob      |1547759154|    1|
|  2  |samantha |1547758879|    1|
|  2  |eric     |1547759154|    1|
+-----+---------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am a newbie so I am not sure. But I tried: `df.select("id", df.events.value, fn.explode(df.events.key).alias("keys")).\
    withColumn("values", fn.explode(df.events.value)).\
        select("id","keys", "values").show(truncate=False)`. 
But it raises an error.

Comment: Add you code **and the full error message** to your question. It is not readable in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.select("id", fn.explode(df.events).alias('events')). \
    select("id", fn.col("events").getItem("key").alias("key"),
           fn.col("events").getItem("value").alias("value"),
           fn.col("events").getItem("timestamp").alias("timestamp"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` to split each element of the array into its own row, then just `select` the individual elements of the structure.

```
case class Event(key: String, timestamp: Long, value: String)
val df = List((1, Seq(Event("john", 1547758879, "1"), 
                      Event("bob", 1547759154, "1"))), 
              (2, Seq(Event("samantha", 1547758879, "1"), 
                      Event("eric", 1547759154, "1")))
             ).toDF("id","events")

df.show(false)
/*--+--------------------------------------------------+
|id |events                                            |
+---+--------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[[john, 1547758879, 1], [bob, 1547759154, 1]]     |
|2  |[[samantha, 1547758879, 1], [eric, 1547759154, 1]]|
+---+-------------------------------------------------*/

val exploded = df.withColumn("events", explode($"events"))
exploded.show(false)
/*--+-------------------------+
|id |events                   |
+---+-------------------------+
|1  |[john, 1547758879, 1]    |
|1  |[bob, 1547759154, 1]     |
|2  |[samantha, 1547758879, 1]|
|2  |[eric, 1547759154, 1]    |
+---+------------------------*/

val unstructured = exploded.select($"id", $"events.key", $"events.timestamp", $"events.value")
unstructured.show
/*--+--------+----------+-----+
| id|     key| timestamp|value|
+---+--------+----------+-----+
|  1|    john|1547758879|    1|
|  1|     bob|1547759154|    1|
|  2|samantha|1547758879|    1|
|  2|    eric|1547759154|    1|
+---+--------+----------+----*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach:

1. Add a count of how many elements are in each `events` row:

```py
## recreate the dataframe sample
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1, [['john' , 1547758879, 1], ['bob', 1547759154, 1]]],
        [2, [['samantha' , 1547758879, 1], ['eric', 1547759154, 1]]]
    ], columns = ['id','events']
)

df['elements'] = df['events'].apply(lambda x: len(x))

Out[36]: 
   id                                             events  elements
0   1      [[john, 1547758879, 1], [bob, 1547759154, 1]]         2
1   2  [[samantha, 1547758879, 1], [eric, 1547759154,1]]         2
```

2. Flatten the nested results into one list of lists:

```py
values = df['events'].values.flatten().tolist()
flat_results = [item for sublist in values for item in sublist]

>> flat_results
Out[38]: 
[['john', 1547758879, 1],
 ['bob', 1547759154, 1],
 ['samantha', 1547758879, 1],
 ['eric', 1547759154, 1]]
```

3. Create a new DataFrame from the the flattened list

```py
new_df = pd.DataFrame(flat_results, columns=['key','timestamp','value'])
```

4. Use the element count to repeat the id from the original source

```py
new_df['id'] = df['id'].repeat(df['elements'].values).values

>> new_df
Out[40]: 
        key   timestamp  value  id
0      john  1547758879      1   1
1       bob  1547759154      1   1
2  samantha  1547758879      1   2
3      eric  1547759154      1   2
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is in pyspark, I am not sure how to do that without transforming to a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Oh I took it as entirely a `pandas` problem. My apologies @user3192082